# Android: Create ListView in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm creating `ListView` in `AsyncTask` inside `Fragment`. In `onActivityCreated` method i call `AsyncTask's execute()` method, but after `onPause()` when I resume activity, my list is empty. Should I call `execute()` method again in `onResume()`? Thank you.

Comment: where have you put setContentView??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You have to call execute on `onResume()`. For more information about activity cycle see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).